Need to power 800 sf tiny house 350 feet from transformer
I have a 800 ft.² tiny house that I need to run power to.
Based on load calculations, I need a 70 amp service feeder.
The only major electrical appliances include three 12,000 BTU mini splits and a standard residential refrigerator.
I will be tying power into a service panel that is basically right next to the transformer.
The wire will have to run 350 feet to tie into a separate 100 amp subpanel inside the tiny house.
I’ve been told that 4 wire 1/0 aluminum urd will work.
Given voltage drop considerations do you believe the 1/0 aluminum URD wire will work?

How the heck do you need three 12k mini splits for 800sf? My last house was 2200sf and the three 12k mini splits it had were overkill. The current house is 1700sf and has a 36k heat pump and it's also bigger than needed.

Yep, that's absurd overkill. Unless you're in the desert with no insulation one unit is plenty. If you are in the desert with no insulation you should seriously consider your environmental impact.

Or this? Running a 50amp 240V line 300 feet to a shed

In what country does the transformer wire run into a panel inside the house?

Or this? What size wire do I need for a 100amp underground 300 ft run?

There are two bedrooms and a living space.  The mini splits are not ducted and the rooms are all closed off from each other meaning there is no way for efficient airflow, thus the need for each room to have its own wall unit.
Also, I’m not tying into the transformer.  I’m trying into a panel close to the transformer.

Man, I wish I had enough money to call 800 square feet a "tiny house"

Okay, it was not at all clear that you were talking about two different panels at the same time.  I will try to help edit your question.

@JohnAllen You still don't buy 3 12k mini-splits. You buy a multi-split system that has one outdoor unit and 3 indoor units.

Size those bedroom units down! Unless you live in Arizona with awful insulation, a 6k unit is going to be plenty. And all three can run off a single outdoor unit and circuit. That alone will probably get you down to a 50 amp service.

Using the Southwire Voltage Drop Calculator and 350 feet, 1/0 aluminum wire, 240V and 70A, the result is 4.25% drop. That's not too bad. However, at 120V it is 8.50%. So a key issue is 120V vs. 240V loads and how well balanced the system is.
I would definitely consider upsizing. At 2/0, the 240V 70A drop goes down to 3.32%, which is close to the mythical ideal of 3%.
You may also want to consider conduit instead of cable. Yes, conduit + wires will probably cost more in terms of material than direct burial cable. But you may make up for it in labor/installation cost, and you then have more/better options for dealing with future upgrades or (if something messes up wire in conduit, which is less likely than something messing up direct burial cable but could still happen) repairs. Plus you may be able to run a fiber optic cable for internet access through the same conduit.
Burial depths:

Direct burial: 24"
PVC Conduit 18"
Rigid Metal Conduit or Intermediate Metal Conduit 6"

Note that conduit depth is 18" under certain types of driveways and parking areas and 24" under others. But those are usually only a small part of a 350' run.
350' is a long distance. If it is basically flat, clear area then 24" isn't so bad because you rent equipment and/or hire a company to trench through the whole thing quickly. But if it is "over the river and through the woods" then trenching deep is a lot harder to do.
